# Is it still diacope if the words have different inflections?

Tags: rhetoric

1. "They will laugh, indeed they will laugh, at his parchment and his wax." ―Edmund Burke
2. "With eager feeding food doth choke the feeder." ―William Shakespeare

I know the first sentence is an example of diacope, but what about the second? Can *feeding* and *feeder* be considered diacope even though the words have different inflections?

Comment: I would consider the second example a play on words, but not an example of diacope.

Comment: It's not a diacope, rather it could be **Polyptoton**: Repetition of words of the same root with different endings. *No end to the **withering** of **withered** flowers; To the **drift** of the sea and the **drifting** wreckage;  barely **prayable Prayer** of the one Annunciation…* http://literarydevices.net/Polyptoton/

Comment: "the word “drift” (noun and adjective) and the word “pray” have been used to give different senses (adjective and noun) each time." (ibid.) In OP's second example sentence, a gerund (nominal) and a noun.

Comment: *Still **works** as once it **worked*** C.S. Lewis, *The Meteorite*.

Comment: @Kris Why do you people from certain Regions have this curious habit of capitalizing a Word in isolation, whether as a use–mention distinction or for some other purpose? This is undone in Standard English but occurs commonly from Asian speakers.

Comment: @tchrist Brush up on "Standard English," if there's such a thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

This may fall to a matter of opinion, but I would say that number 2 is *not* an example of diacope.

As a rhetorical device, its action stems from very specific choices of wording. A diacope is specifically the repetition of an identical word. There are related devices ([epizeuxis](http://literarydevices.net/Epizeuxis/) and epanalepsis) that differ by the distance between the repeated words.

As Kris indicated in [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180062/question-about-diacope-and-inflections#comment373482_180062), this is more likely a [Polyptoton](http://literarydevices.net/Polyptoton/). There's a nice overview of [repetition devices](http://literarydevices.net/repetition/) that outlines their differences.